# ios - NSString losing content when used in NSUrl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsurl

I have the following code - note it has to objects with temp, but I will explain.

```
NSString *temp =  _passedOnURL;
NSString *temp = @"http://google.com"; //I comment the one out that I do not use.

NSLog(@"TEMP - %@", temp);

NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:temp];
NSLog(@"FEED URL - %@", feedURL);
```

The _passedOnURL is a string with the contents passed from a Segue.

Now when I use the 1st temp, the FEED URL returns (null), but when I Log Temp it is still there, so somehow the NSURL does not read the string.

When I hardcode the string with the second temp - there is no issue.

In my mind there is no difference for the NSURL when it is reading the NSString yet, it seems to behave different.

Is there any reason for this??

EDIT

When I do the following code I have no issues:

```
_passedOnURL = @"http://www.google.com";
```

so I really have no explanation for this???

Comment: Yes I am - Arc is on for the whole project

Comment: What do you get when you do NSLog(@"%@", [_passedOnURL class] ) ?

Comment: It returns this   =>> __NSCFString

Comment: the url you have in _passedOnURL is valid?

Comment: Yes, it works. It's an RSS feed but a long one, but google.com has the same result.

Comment: try escaping it : [NSURL URLWithString: [temp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                              NSASCIIStringEncoding]]

Comment: That does change it - it adds @%22 on either side of the url, now to get it working without those bits and I am good;-)

Comment: %22 is for the double quote, so it seems your string has the quotes on it which makes it non-valid

Comment: Ah yes that was it - I had @"http://the url" - when I removed the quotes it was sorted:-)

Comment: Yep, the string you're passing to URLWithString is not a valid URL.

Comment: If you write it up in an answer, I will accept it thanks:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try escaping it : [NSURL URLWithString: [temp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]]

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have an invalid url string stored in temp. Not every string can be converted to a url but the valid url. Invalid chars and format will lead a nil object after +URLWithString:. So would you let us know what is stored in temp when you try this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc for URLWithString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString%3a)

> **Parameters**
>   *URLString*
>
> The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL
>   that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to
>   RFCs 1738 and 1808.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string was
>   malformed, returns nil.

So my guess is that your `_passedOnURL` is not a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a NSLog on your _passedOnURL to check if you are getting the string correctly from the other segue.

Comment: I am - when I do an NSLog on _passedOnURL - they are identical